# jQuery getting label for checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

In my below code, I keep getting "MexicoMexico" returned as the label text when I check "Mexico". For all the other fields I am not getting this duplicate result, it is only for this one field. The issue occurs immediately after the first assignment of countryvalues[i] and I don't see why.

```
<div id="country">
....
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="mexico" class="checkbox">
   <label for="mexico">Mexico</label></input></li>
</div>

countryvalues = $('#country input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get(); 
for (var i=0; i<countryvalues.length; i++)
    {
        countryvalues[i] = $("label[for='" + countryvalues[i] + "']").text();
        countryvalues[i] = countryvalues[i].split(' ').join('%20');
        fields = fields + "coveraa!";
        url = url + countryvalues[i] + "!";
    }
```

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/j2X7Q/1/

Comment: Do the other countries also have `</input>`, or are their input tags self-closed with `<input ... />`? As far as I'm aware a closing `</input>` is not legal under all Doctypes, and may give varied/unknown behaviour in different browsers.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for the mention, unfortunately it did not solve the double Mexico problem.

Comment: `alert(countryvalues).length`. What value do you get?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot 1!

Comment: 1 is good. I can only agree that 'MexicoMexico' is very odd if the other countries are OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sarina, I can only suggest you try obtaining the string you seek within the `.map()` callback rather than looping again with `for(...){...}`.

```
var countryvalues = $('#country input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).next("label").text().split(' ').join('%20');
}).get();
```

Make sure the HTML is purged of all instances of `</input>` and that the input elements are self-closed, `<input ... />`.

Comment: silly me, I hadn't realized that Mexico appeared in another div, doing it this way removed the issue

Comment: Ah, there had to be an explanation. Now we can all celebrate by dancing on our hats :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple  `li` . then you can use this code to get the checked `checkbox` label text.

[JS FIDLLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/C4GJH/1/)

```
<div id="country">
....
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="mexico" class="checkbox">
   <label for="mexico">Mexico</label></input>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="country" value="mexico" class="checkbox">
   <label for="mexico">Canada</label></input>
    </li>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country li input:checkbox').change(
        function() {
            //alert('HI');
            alert($(this).next('label').text());
                   }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example and you get the script how to get label of checkbox in jQuery

```
<html>
 <body>
     <ul>
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="mouse" value="1" id="mouse"  /><label for="mouse">Mouse</label>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="keyboard" value="1" id="keyboard"  /><label for="mouse">Keyboard</label>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="monitor" value="1" id="monitor"  /><label for="mouse">Monitor</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var label = jQuery('label[for=' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ']').html();
 alert(label);
</script>
```

Code taken from here :  http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-get-checkbox-label-text-jquery.html