# How to get text() from checkbox if is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, checkbox

I know this question has been asked many times, and I have found a few answers on how to get `text()` from checkbox, but when I tried to get text only from checked one, is when my code has some errors.

Consider this code:

```js
$('input.choose-age').on('change', function() {
  $('input.choose-age').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label for='wom-10-14' class="checkbox-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" id='wom-10-14' class='choose-age' checked />10-14
  </label>
  <label for='wom-15-19' class="checkbox-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" id='wom-15-19' class='choose-age' />15-19
  </label>
  <label for='wom-10-19' class="checkbox-inline">
 <input type="checkbox" id='wom-10-19' class='choose-age' />10-19
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to select `text()` from checkbox if is checked and save it into a `var`. I am using `d3.js` and `mapbox` to run a mapDraw function, so I want to change indicators if a different checkbox is checked.

I know that this example returns the text, however is not what I'm looking for:

```
var ageLab = $('label[for=wom-10-14]').text();
```

This is what I tried:

**1.**

```
var ageLab = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).prev('label.checkbox-inline').text();
}).get();

console.log(ageLab);
```

*Source: [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871997/jquery-getting-label-for-checked-checkbox)*

It returns:

```
Array[1]
    0: ""
    length: 1
```

**2**

```
var ageLab = $('.choose-age:checked').text(this.checked ? $(this).text() : '');
```

*Source: [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851006/get-value-if-checkbox-checked)*

However, it doesn´t returns text.

Is there a better way to get `text()` from checkbox when is checked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `.text()` or text property for checkbox elements as they are empty ones. Either you can get the value of them, if defined, else, we can make a different approach.

**Closest**

```
var ageLab = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).closest('label.checkbox-inline').text();
}).get();
```

**Span**

```
<input type="checkbox" id='wom-10-14' class='choose-age' checked /> <span>10-14</span>
```

```
var ageLab = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
  return $(this).next('span').text();
}).get();
```

> **Note:** If you want only one selected, why not go for `:radio` in contrast to `:checkbox`?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, @Praveen. `span` is much better and `:radio` will be also a better choice.